Cardinality of relative constructible set L(B,C,$\alpha$)
There is a result (Proposition 17.60 in Monk - Notes on Set Theory) saying that assuming ZFC, for all infinite ordinals $\alpha$, the cardinality of a relative constructible set in $V$ is
\begin{equation}
\vert L(B,C,\alpha)\vert=\vert \alpha\vert +\vert \lbrace C\rbrace\cup\operatorname{trcl}(C)\vert.\nonumber
\end{equation}
My question is: how to prove this formula when $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal? Since we have proved this formula for the case of successor ordinals, by the inductive hypothesis, it is clear that for any ordinals $\omega\leq \beta\leq \alpha$,
\begin{equation}
\vert \beta\vert+\vert \lbrace C\rbrace\cup\operatorname{trcl}(C)\vert\leq \vert L(B,C,\alpha)\vert.\nonumber
\end{equation}
Then, it is clear that
\begin{equation}
\vert L(B,C,\alpha)\vert=\bigcup_{\beta<\alpha}(\vert\beta\vert+\vert\lbrace C\rbrace\cup\operatorname{trcl}(C)\vert).\nonumber
\end{equation}
But how could this lead to the statement above? Thanks in advance for any comments and suggestions.

B appears on the left side, but not on the right.

Are we talking about cardinality in $V$ or the relative constructible universe? And do we assume the axiom of choice in $V$?

It is about the cardinality in $V$, and we assume ZFC. This result is Proposition 17.60 in Notes on Set Theory (https://euclid.colorado.edu/~monkd/full.pdf).

For those who want to know, in Monk's notation $L(B,C,\alpha)$ is the level $\alpha$ result of starting the constructibility hierarchy with ${C}\cup\text{trcl}(C)$ and allowing $B$ as a predicate for definability at successor stages.
